# What is the best way to make my Mac's photo library the master?

Tags: icloud, photos

I want my photos library on my iMac to be the master library. 
I keep experimenting trying to get it this to work efficiently, but keep failing.
Right now,
On my iPhone, I have “iCloud Photos” on, and “Upload to My Photo Stream on.
On my iPad, I have “iCloud Photos” off and “My Photo Stream” on.
On my Mac, I have System Preferences/Apple ID/Photos checked

To get photos to my iMac, I have been selecting photos one by one and forwarding them to myself in order to manually put on my Photos.

Is that the way it’s supposed to work?   If not, what am I doing wrong?